# Animation bug, precedence of animation, when animation applied to child and parent

Tags: css, css-animations

I just built a small animation and it does exactly as I want it to, except a small problem, I have bounceIn animation on 2 HTML elements, my HTML is below:

```
<div class="test animated bounceInDown"> 
    <span class="animated bounceInDown delay">I am animation</span> 
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.test {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    display: table;
}
.test span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
.delay {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
    0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: none;
    }
}
.bounceInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
    animation-name: bounceInDown;
}
```

Now of course span is a child of the div, on the span I have a animation-delay, problem is, the animation on the span has a small bug: it follows the animation of the div and then executes its own animation, I.E. on page load, the span element still bounces in with the div even though I have an animation delay.

I am more interested in **WHY** this is happening than **HOW** to solve my problem. Here's a fiddle to see what I am talking about: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ev5ur00n/)

Comment: with a shorter delay, the animation seems more fluid: http://jsfiddle.net/gael/83867y1r/

Comment: @Gael , hmmmm interesting . but i really want my question answered , anyways , will try what u've said too .

Comment: @Gael , Ohhh yessss !!!!! I think i'am closer to the solution . shorter delay , yeah right !

Comment: Actually, I do not really understand what you are trying to do!

Comment: It all eventually has to go in a carousel  http://jsfiddle.net/Ld8f0Luu/

Comment: and your problem is?

Comment: huh ? was my question not clear enuf ? and what if i don't want to have a short delay , but a long delay , but at the same time , i don't want the element to show before the animation activates . clear enuf ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong about your animation. Just that the configuration of your animation is not good.

The problem appear because before the animation trigger. The `text` will be render within the animating parent.

When your `text` got triggered by animation it will animation on it own. Which mean it will be move up with 3000px.

=> should concern about animation a `child` in within an animating `parent`.

When you apply animation to an element, all child elements too undergo the animation. So, in your case, `span` tag too animates with the parent.

After time in `animation-delay`'s value passes after page load, the animation on child `span` takes place.

**This isn't a bug. Its the way animations work on child elements.**

---

**To fix the problem**: Just simply use `opacity` with your animation and `animation-fill-mode` and it will do the trick

http://jsfiddle.net/ev5ur00n/2/

```css
.test {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:yellow;
    display: table;
}
.test span {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -o-animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
.delay {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounceInDown {
    0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {
        transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    }
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translate3d(0, -3000px, 0);
    }
    60% {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translate3d(0, 25px, 0);
    }
    75% {
        transform: translate3d(0, -10px, 0);
    }
    90% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 5px, 0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: none;
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
.bounceInDown {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
    animation-name: bounceInDown;
}

.bounceInDown2 {
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceInDown;
    animation-name: bounceInDown;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="test animated bounceInDown"> 
    <span class="animated bounceInDown2 delay">I am animation</span> 
</div>
```

Comment: I think its the correct explanation. I have edited your answer a bit. If you think it isn't useful, then you should rollback to first version.

Comment: @ThePragmatick Thank you, you are the man! I was like *not sure if anyone get what I said* -_-